# How do you remove the drawing canvas in Ms Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-office-2013

I'm looking around for the option

in Word 2003 and eg 2010, it was tools..options..general..

http://msofficesupport.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/turn-drawing-canvas-on-or-off.html

"automatically create drawing canvas.."

[image]

I have classic menu for ms office, it gives me a tools menu, then rather than options it has "word options",

[image]

and it has general tab but the option is not there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the ribbon, (not the classic menu you/I have) choose File, then there is an 'options'.

Which is the same as tools..word options, that you have in your menu.

But the option to automatically create drawing canvas, has moved from the general tab to the advanced tab, which has loads of options and even as scrollbar, but the option is quite an early one in that tab.

[image]